# Intercepting and Disabling Global Mouse Events

Tags: windows, winapi, mouseevent

I have a problem with my mouse. Every now and then it will double click when I only single click. I know this is a problem with the mouse, and I've contacted the manufacturer, still waiting for a reply. But in the meantime I was wondering if there was a way that I could find out when the left mouse button had been clicked twice within a very short period (probably 1-10 milliseconds) of time, and disable the second click.

I mostly know how to use hooks, so that's not the problem, my main question is how to stop an event from happening, if that's possible.

Comment: This question relates to Windows, not C++. You should retag it.

Comment: This is as unpractical as hoping that you'll get a solution from the manufacturer.  Buy another mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information on how to prevent the mouse message from being processed is in the documentation of the "LowLevelMouseProc callback function" in MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx
Specifically, it says: "If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure." So, if you know about windows hooks, you know how to do it.

**EDIT:** Actually, now that I think more about it, you don't want to discard any event. You simply want to transform the doubleclick event into just another left-button-down event. I believe you can do it from within the hook handler, and it will work. Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tried that, thanks for the information and idea, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

In C#'s WinForms, you write an event handler involving the mouse receiving a MouseEventArgs object. Inside it, you can access certain info such as the number of times it was clicked, for example.

```
protected void RowClicked(object sender, MouseEventArgs evt)
{
    // Trigger it when the mouse was clicked only once
    if( evt.Button.Clicks == 1 ) {
        // ... more things ...
    }

    return;
}
```

Other GUI libraries have other possibilities. That said, your problem has nothing to do with GUI libraries. You have to change the sensitivity of your mouse, in the configuration options of your operating system. For example, in the Windows' control panel, you can change how much time has to pass between a click and another one to be considered a doble-click. In lUbuntu, you can do the very same, in System menu >> Preferences >> Keyboard and Mouse.

Comment: The title of the question says "Intercepting and Disabling Global Mouse Events".